# Running the shell scripts in Background

Tags: linux, unix, shell, scripting

I would to give the user the feature to run the shell script in background.

My shell program instantiates a number of other shell scripts.

Here is a small code snippet of my script

```
./main.sh  # Main script

in main.sh 

I call preprocessing.sh
create_dir.sh
handle_file.sh
post_processing.sh
report_generation.sh
```

I would like to know if I have to initiate all the child script as well.. What is the syntax if i have to initiate all the scripts in background and at the end inform the user by displaying message in  that test run is complete.

Thanks

Kiran

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by backgrounding, exactly?  That you script(s) continue to run even if your connection gets lost/terminal window gets closed?  That you can continue to do work while the script(s) run in the background and are informed at the end of the status?  But what if you're typing a command when the status `echo` comes back and displays a message string in the middle of your typing?

Comment: Yes, I would like to run the script in the background and continue to run other commands in the same shell. After the complete execution, I can inform the user through a simple echo message that it is complete and you can check the log file. 

My script run for nearly 2 hours so I would like to run it in background.

Thanks

Kiran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start your processes in the background with `&` and then use bash's builtin `wait` command:

```
  wait [n ...] 
          Wait for each specified process and return its termination  sta‐ 
          tus.   Each  n  may be a process ID or a job specification; if a 
          job spec is given, all processes  in  that  job’s  pipeline  are 
          waited  for.
```

A couple of example are available [here](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/1724/one-liner-bash-wait-command/). For instance:

```
# wait on 2 processes
sleep 10 &
sleep 10 &
wait %1 %2 && echo "Completed!"
```

Comment: are you sure that this is what you're looking for?? based on your script names it would appear that the sub-scripts must run sequentially, not all together in parallel (which is what the solution you accepted proposes.)

Answer (score 0):

add "&" to the end of the commands

```
I call preprocessing.sh &
create_dir.sh &
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, But How do I inform the user at the end of the test run by a simple echo message.. ??